# Concatenate columns using a macro in DBT for Redshift

Tags: sql, macros, concatenation, dbt

I want to concatenate a few columns using `column1 ^^ column2 ^^ ...` syntax in DBT for Redshift. If there are NULL values in the columns `@@` should be used, resulting in f.e. `@@ ^^ @@`. I have found the following macro for concatenation:

```
{% macro safe_concat(field_list) %}
  {# Takes an input list and generates a concat() statement with each argument in the list safe_casted to a string and wrapped in an ifnull() #}
  concat({% for f in field_list %}
    ifnull(safe_cast({{ f }} as string), '@@')
    {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
  {% endfor %})
{% endmacro %}
```

When I use it in my select statement:

```
select
  {{ safe_concat([street, city]) }} as address_key
from source
```

I get the following error. Is this related to the code I am using?

```
Database Error in model address (models/address.sql)
  syntax error at or near "as"
  LINE 32:     ifnull(safe_cast( as string), '@@')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your column names in quotes when you call them in the macro - I think it’s trying to pass in the variables `street` and `city` (because you’re already inside of curly braces), which don’t exist so are evaluating to `None`

Comment: If I wrap the column names in quotes this is what I get:
  
    ```syntax error at or near "as"
        LINE 32:     ifnull(safe_cast(street as string), '@@')
                                       ^
        compiled SQL at target/run/project/models/address.sql```

Comment: Could you possibly show us the raw and compiled SQL, with the quotes?

Comment: This is the compiled output of the macro (invoked as `{{ safe_concat(['street', 'city']) }} as address_key,`):
```concat(
    ifnull(safe_cast(street as string), '@@')
    , 
  
    ifnull(safe_cast(city as string), '@@')
    
  )```

Comment: Forgot to mention that Redshift is the target database, modified the question accordingly. This is then related to the flavour of functions that are used in the macro.

Answer (score 0):

you can try pushing every loop into an array and then you can use evaluated strings.and also for concat func. you can use '~' this.

```
{% set query_results = [] %}
{% for f in field_list %}
    
    {% set x =  ifnull(safe_cast({{ f }} as string), '@@') ~ '^^' %}
    {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% set query_results = query_results.append(x) %} 
  {% endfor %}
...
return{{query_results }}
```